# Ensure that String has no sequences of a certain character (.)

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have already found a solution but I am wondering if it can be made more efficient or more readable.

Users of my app can enter their full name, like `”Paul McCartney”`, and I am suggesting a short *username* based on that. *Username*s should accept only lowercase letters, numbers and dots (.). To explain, let me show how I do it (might be flawed, you are welcome to improve it):

```
public static String formatUsername(String source) {
    return source
            .trim()
            .toLowerCase()
            .replaceAll("\\s", ".") // replace spaces with dots
            .replaceAll("[^a-z[0-9][\\.]]+", "") // remove all the rest
            .replaceAll("[\\.]{2,}", "."); // avoid sequences of dots like “.."
}
```

The result is `paul.mccartney`.

Now I also need a function that tells me if a certain String is an *acceptable* username. Checking for characters is easy:

```
return Pattern.matches("[a-z[0-9][\\.]]+", input)
```

But I want to avoid sequences of two or more dots, e.g. `paul..mccartney` is **not okay**. I have tried with `"[a-z[0-9][\\.]?]+"`, but it doesn’t work. Currently I’m using this:

```
return Pattern.matches("[a-z[0-9][\\.]]+", shortName)
    && !Pattern.compile("[\\.]{2,}").matcher(shortName).find();
```

but I feel like there exists a better solution, more readable at least.

Comment: regex is not the only way to go if( source.indexOf("..") > -1) return false

Comment: Your regex does not allow Unicode letters. Is it on purpose?

Comment: @Wiktor no, in the sense that I have not thought about it. By unicode letters you mean your ż , for example? Are these usually accepted in usernames? Looks so judging by your username here, but, for example, could you put that in a twitter @username?

Comment: Twitter usernames seem to follow the `@\w+` pattern. Well, I just asked :)

Comment: @Wiktor I’ll think about it. Usernames in my app are used to log in. The worst scenario I can think about it is that I let you use ż but someday you happen to have an input interface that has no ż s and you are left out. I wonder how much a user like you is disappointed to be forced to transliterate. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to validate:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[a-z0-9.]+$
```

`(?!.*\.\.)` is negative lookahead assertion to fail the match if `..` appear anywhere.

In Java:

```
boolean valid = input.matches("^(?!.*\\.\\.)[a-z0-9.]+$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jS7tX6/2)

Comment: Thank you, but that’s not perfectly what I am looking for. For example this misses `.paul` or `paul.`, which for me are valid. I don’t ask for a `firstname.lastname` pattern, dots are enabled everywhere as long as there are no sequences of two or more.

Comment: Just gotta escape the period in the pattern, otherwise this looks good.

Comment: Inside `[...]` you don't need to escape the DOT

Answer (score 1):

The order and a non-regex replace.

```
public static String formatUsername(String source) {
    return source
            .toLowerCase()
            .replaceAll("\\W+", " ") // non-word chars with space
            .trim()
            .replace(' ', '.');
}
```

(This allows underscore too.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew copy error; trim had to come after replaceAll

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the interest, but char sequences like `$`  or `+`  or space (non-word, `\W`) first are converted to space, which `trim()` can chop off on both ends, and then all spaces become dots.